# Erro ao iniciar Jboos 7.1 Address already in use: JVM_Bind /0.0.0.0:80

Tags: jboss

Estou tentando iniciar meu servidor Jboss 7.1 com uma nova aplicação, porém está ocorrendo o erro:

```
[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error initializing endpoint: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind /0.0.0.0:80
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
```

Geralmente(ao menos comigo) isso ocorre por conflito com as portas utilizadas pelo Skype, que já alterei.

Acessei o prompt de comando executando o comando `netstat -aob` para verificar que programa está utilizando essa porta, e me diz que é o sistema, e não foi possível obter informações de propriedade.

Alguém já passou por esse problema e poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: Você têm o MS SQL instalado?

Comment: Estava pesquisando e demorei para ver sua postagem, desculpe.
Verifiquei que tenho instalado o SQL Server 2014, e 3 programas desse pacote estavam rodando: SQL Server, SQL Server Agent e SQL Server Browser, onde encerrei os 2 últimos citados e consegui iniciar meu servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifiquei que tenho instalado o SQL Server 2014, e 3 programas desse pacote estavam rodando: SQL Server, SQL Server Agent e SQL Server Browser, onde encerrei os 2 últimos citados e consegui iniciar meu servidor.